# The way to change @Id in child class

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have the Parent class that has field notated with org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

```
class Parent { @Id private String baseId; ...}
```

and now I need to extend all the properties of parent class but change @Id field

```
class Child extends { @Id private String childID; ...}
```

do you anyone how to make this work ?

Comment: class Child extends Parent { @Id private String childID; ...}

Comment: What is your use case ? What is the problem you are running into when doing that ?